# Howto find a file that is lost because of "git merge master -s ours"

Tags: git

Is there a way to find a merge that removed a file from a project if this file was created after the branch? The following steps to reproduce my problem should clarify:

- git init
- touch file1
- git add file1
- git commit file1 -m "added file1 in master"
- git branch newbranch
- touch file2
- git add file2
- git commit file2 -m "added file2 in master after branching"
- echo "master changes to file1" >> file1
- git commit file1 -m "changed file1 in master"
- git checkout newbranch
- echo "newbranch changes to file1" >> file1
- git commit file1 -m "changed file1 in newbranch"
- git merge master -s ours
- touch file3
- git add file3
- git commit file3 -m "added file3 in newbranch"
- git checkout master
- touch file4
- git add file4
- git commit file4 -m "added file4 in master"
- git merge newbranch

Now, how is it possible to find the commit (merge) that removed file2 (I mean the merge that happend in this line/command: "git merge master -s ours").

EDIT:

- git log --graph --format=oneline

```
*   010a604feef300244386490f9c7c777dc9af6b16 Merge branch 'newbranch'
|\  
| * 3e7f3f6b53c2c92d137fa5a3bac190aa4c3e641f added file3 in newbranch
| *   b07090c2c6dd5cd2783f3db160f5b6f433beb544 Merge branch 'master' into newbranch
| |\  
| * | a0053413ab81869574475c0ce889ee721f5ed254 changed file1 in newbranch4
* | | 859e813acd24c2090287ef9d83da339c06f1c754 added file4 in master
| |/  
|/|   
* | 0004dc5cfe23874208c6a921f9c7434fcffba8f4 changed file1 in master
* | 172d20a93ba40fb040348acc5ffe2ad45803ec22 added file2 in master after branching
|/  
* 6a59be0a3d4203db84b67c02231c420b518fc349 added file1 in master
```

The commit I am looking for is: **b07090c2c6dd5cd2783f3db160f5b6f433beb544**

- git log -g --diff-filter=D -- file2

returns: commit 6a59be0a3d4203db84b67c02231c420b518fc349

- git log -g --diff-filter=D --follow -- file2

returns: commit 010a604feef300244386490f9c7c777dc9af6b16

Strangely enough in my repository where I discovered the problem, **git log -g --diff-filter=D -- filename** did give me the correct commit I was looking for.

Comment: Does the reflog help you? http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Comment: * git log -g --diff-filter=D -- <filename>

this didn't work in the example I wrote in my question. It did, however, work for my git reposetory where I had the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be `git log --all --raw --diff-filter=D -m`. The `--all` is to look at all branches instead of just the one you're currently on. I left off `-g` since that only searches the reflogs, and if one or more of the merges were done on another repo, your reflogs may have never visited the commit you're looking for. The `-m` and `--raw` show what happened on each commit including merges (which are usually hidden except for conflicts). This command flags both merges as points where `file2` was deleted, at least for the scenario you posted...